# POST request to parse-server mount with graphql return 400 Bad Request

Tags: parse-platform, graphql

I'm trying the new GraphQL addition to Parse-Server. Tried to do a simple query but response is

> POST '[parse-server address]' net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)
>
> Access to fetch at '[parse-server address]' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

The Parse GraphQL API guide did not state what is expected from request header, so I'm trying to figure out what should be added into the request header.

Parse-Server version 3.6.0 running on heroku, client request from react 16.8.3 running on localhost.

The request from GraphQL Console in Parse-Dashboard return the correct output with no error, so the parse-server setup should not be a problem. I've allowed CORS in the server and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is set to 'http://localhost:3000'. I'm guessing the request header is missing some values so I added "X-Parse-Application-Id" & "X-Parse-Master-Key".

Simple client request using Lokka:

client.query(
  `{
    query Health {
      health
    }
  }`
).then(result => {
  console.log(result.health);
});

I expect the response should be 200 as in the GraphQL console, but response is 400 Bad Request.

Comment: When you say `parse-server address`, is it the GraphQL endpoint? Can you double check if you are really sending the request to the GraphQL endpoint (it is different from the rest endpoint).

Comment: I've compared with request from Parse-dashboard GraphQL Console, it's the same endpoint. Basically instead of "[parse-server address]/parse" for REST API, for GraphQL is to "[parse-server address]/graphql" endpoint

Comment: Can you compare if the headers and body are also the same? Where is your parse dashboard running? In the same domain of parse server? If you run a parse dashboard on localhost, does it also work?